# Accessing a method from a thread in the "mother" class-object that called these thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to call a function in the class which created the thread from this thread.

Currently I have two classes, a *Helper-Class* and my *Async-Worker-Class*.

First my *Helper-Class* is instantiated in my **main()**. The thread is created in the *Helper-Class*. It should be possible to instantiate more than one *Helper-Class*. So, the number of instances and threads are the same.

```c
int main(){
    //This is where my helper is constructed
    Helper myHelper_1();
    Helper myHelper_2();

}
```

Now my helper class looks like this. The constructor of the *Helper-Class* creates a new thread - I have named it *t1*.

```c
class Helper {
    std::stack <std::string> names_for_adding;
    std::mutex helper_lock;

    void processName(std::string name);


    // The constructor of my "mother"-class constructs the thread
    Helper() {
        // I've created an instance of AsyncThread
        AsyncThread my_async_worker();

        //Call the thread
        std::thread t1(&AsyncThread::scan, &my_async_worker);
        t1.detach();

        while(true) {
            std::cout << "Doing some stuff.." << std::endl;

            //Now oi check if my
            helper_lock.lock();
            std::string my_name = names_for_adding.top();
            names_for_adding.pop();
            // E. g. process the name
            processName(my_name);
            helper_lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void addToQueue(std::string name) {
        helper_lock.lock();
        names_for_adding.push(name);
        helper_lock.unlock();
    }
};
```

The second class, the *AsyncThread* has the only purpose of 'scanning' while running. One task could be for example
receiving unperiodically different dates (e.g. names) (from a pipe or a socket).
If a name matches the given filter (e. g. 'foo'), I want to notify my *Helper-Instance* about this and add the found name to a queue for further processing.

```c
class AsyncThread {

public:
    void scan() {
        std::string name;
        //Doing the scan procedure
        //...
        while (true) {
            // ...Receiving names ...
            // A name has been found which matches the given filter
            if (name == "foo") {
                std::cout << "Name found, adding to helper" << std::endl;
                //like: myHelper_1.addToQueue(name)
                //now i want to call the function 'addToQueue' from my
                //my class helper (which is also an object)
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now my question is how to achieve this in a thread-safe way? Is it possible (and allowed or good practice) to pass my thread a reference to the calling Helper-Instance?
My second question is: Is the synchronization I've added sufficient?

Update: I do not want my helper to wait for incoming data. It should be possible to stay in a loop and periodically check if now data has arrived. If new data has been found this should be processed otherwise my helper should continuing doing other stuff.

Comment: That looks OK to me, but you might consider swapping the order of `processName(my_name);` and `helper_lock.unlock();` to minimise the time you hold the lock in the main thread.  Check out also [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) instead of locking and unlocking the mutex manually.

Comment: okay, but how to call the *addToQueue* function from my thread? Should  I pass a reference of my helper instanze to the constructor of the *AsyncThread* thread?

Comment: Sure, why not?  Just be sure to protect any shared data with your mutex (as you are already doing).

Comment: You have several function declarations here that you surely meant to be variables.  You also need to use a condition variable or semaphore to convey the information that a value has been put on the stack (and why not a queue?).

Comment: @Davis Herring Actually, I do not understand what you stated in your first sentence. And I need to use a condition variable to notify my helper that an event occured?

Comment: @agentsmith: See “most vexing parse”.  Mutexes alone are inappropriate for *notifying* one thread of another’s activities (in this case, providing data to process).

Comment: Okay thanks. Unfortunately that does not help solve my problem. I am now working with condition variables and accessing them by passing a reference of the helper to AsyncThread. But I have to declare my condition variable as well as my mutex as public so that the AsyncThread class can lock it. An alternative method would be to write a getter and a setter for the mutex / condition variable, but both methods do not seem to be very elegant.